# Pie Chart in QlikView

Tags: qlikview

I have problem with  Pie Chart , when i have samll number. On the sector the percentages are superimposed and this problem of superposition is related to the values ​​too small.

Does anyone have a solution ie we can display the small values ​​without being superimposed on the level of the graph ??

Can see this link i have put the picutre  :
[enter link description here](https://www.developpez.net/forums/d1886266/logiciels/solutions-d-entreprise/business-intelligence/secteur-in-qlikview/)

Answer (score 0):

In QlikView its a known issue.
What I usually do is go to "dimension limits" -> "show only value that are" -> "greater than" -> 5%.
You can use any number you want - tailored to your needs
All that's below 5% will go into "Other" slice
And by clicking "Other" you can drill down into it.

it looks like this (blue slice it "Other"):
[image]

Comment: Hi , I can't see the image , but i can't do the limite dimension , and i need that if i have like 1% , 2.5% for exemple it will show in the graphique without superimposed

Comment: possible solutions:
1. put the numbers on the legend - you did that and it was not accepted
2. use "limit dimension" - not acceptable
3. switch to QlikSense! - I hate it but the only option left ;)

Comment: So how i can put the number in the legend ? its possible this ??

Comment: I do List Value :

Comment: the problem is this look at my post here :https://www.developpez.net/forums/d1886266/logiciels/solutions-d-entreprise/business-intelligence/secteur-in-qlikview/#post10431134

Answer (score 0):

I put list Value :

```
I do List Value :   (
```

if(ValueList('Attributions  RCI','Promotion RCP','Garanties', 'Promotion RCE') = 'Attributions  RCI', sum({}[Dont COMP]),0)
+if(ValueList('Attributions  RCI','Promotion RCP','Garanties', 'Promotion RCE') = 'Promotion RCP'    , sum({}[Dont EXP]),0)
+if(ValueList('Attributions  RCI','Promotion RCP','Garanties', 'Promotion RCE') = 'Garanties'        , sum({}[Dont COMP]),0)
+if(ValueList('Attributions  RCI','Promotion RCP','Garanties', 'Promotion RCE') = 'Promotion RCE'    , sum({} [Dont RESP]),0)
)
/(sum({} [Dont RESP])
+
sum({}[Dont EXP])
+
sum({}[Dont COMP])
)